# class attribute doesn't get assigned correctly

Tags: python, multithreading, macos, subprocess, python-2.x

I am trying to loop an alarm (in the file `beep.wav`) and show an alert.

Once the alert is closed, I want to *instantly* stop the alarm.

I am attempting a solution which uses threading to control the alarm's playback.

However, it throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 28, in <module>
    thread.stop()
  File "test.py", line 21, in stop
    self.process.kill()
AttributeError: 'AlarmThread' object has no attribute 'process'
```

I don't really know why this error would get thrown, but it looks like `self.process` is, for some reason, not assigned when `AlarmThread.stop` is called.

This makes no sense to me, as from my code it looks like `thread.stop` is only called after `thread.start`:

```
import subprocess
import threading

class AlarmThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, file_name="beep.wav"):
        super(AlarmThread, self).__init__()
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.ongoing = None

    def run(self):
        self.ongoing = True
        while self.ongoing:
            self.process = subprocess.Popen(["afplay", self.file_name])
            self.process.wait()

    def stop(self):
        if self.ongoing is not None:
            self.ongoing = False
            self.process.kill()

thread = AlarmThread()
thread.start()
# show_alert is synchronous, an alert must be closed before the script continues
show_alert("1 second timer")

thread.stop()
thread.join()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a race condition. The thread hasn't had time to start, create the process and assign `self.process` by the time you call `thread.stop()`. You could initialize `self.process` in `__init__` and use that to see if the process is really there

```
import subprocess
import threading

class AlarmThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, file_name="beep.wav"):
        super(AlarmThread, self).__init__()
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.ongoing = False
        self.process = None

    def run(self):
        self.ongoing = True
        while True:
            with self.lock:
                if not self.ongoing:
                    break
                self.process = subprocess.Popen(["afplayer", self.file_name])
            self.process.wait()

    def stop(self):
        with self.lock:
            if self.ongoing:
                self.ongoing = False
                if self.process:
                    self.process.kill()


thread = AlarmThread()
thread.start()
# show_alert is synchronous, an alert must be closed before the script continues
show_alert("1 second timer")

thread.stop()
thread.join()
```

Comment: should the `if self.process` be a `while not self.process: pass` to wait until the thread is ready to be killed?

Comment: @minseong - I added some locks to plug the holes. It worked in some hacked up tests I wrote. Can you test in your environment?

Comment: Does using locks have any benefits compared with my own solution (below)?

Comment: Yes. Consider `self.process = subprocess.Popen(["afplayer", self.file_name])`. The Popen takes a significant amount of time and you could be in the middle of that call when the other thread checks for `self.process == None`. its None at the time of the check... but then is assigned. Similar problems in the gap between when you check `self.ongoing` and the actions you take afterwards.

Comment: I was trying to be clever in the order I checked the variables but still had problems in the first non-locking revision.

Comment: I don't get what you mean; why should I use locks instead of just waiting for process to be assigned?

Comment: I put a comment on your answer to hopefully be less confusing. When closing race conditions, you can narrow them and not realize you haven't closed them completely. I think the lock slams the door.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it was caused by a race condition.

> The thread hasn't had time to start, create the process and assign `self.process` by the time you call `thread.stop()`

However, I found a fix that relied upon simply waiting until `thread.process` was assigned:

```
thread = AlarmThread()
thread.start()
while not thread.process:
    time.sleep(0.1)

show_alert(message)

thread.stop()
thread.join()
```

My class also changed slightly to ensure `thread.process` is always assigned:

```
class AlarmThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, file_name="beep.wav"):
        super(AlarmThread, self).__init__()
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.ongoing = None
        self.process = None

    def run(self):
        self.ongoing = True
        while self.ongoing:
            self.process = subprocess.Popen(["afplay", self.file_name])
            self.process.wait()
            self.process = None

    def stop(self):
        if self.ongoing is not None:
            self.ongoing = False
            self.process.kill()
```

Comment: Looking at `run`, there is a window between when `self.ongoing` is set and when `self.process` is actually assigned (executing "afplay" takes a significant amount of time for instance). That gap exists on each loop because `self.process = None`. Also, `self.ongoing` should only be True/False ... you set it to `False` but check for `None`.